# header('Location: ..') is sending get request, and not redirecting

Tags: php, angularjs, redirect, authentication, header

I am trying to redirect user after login, but instead of redirecting, the **GET** request is being sent and the page remains the same. I would like to avoid redirection from front-end, since I have to set up some parameters for the session.

This is the login script:

```
require_once("../data/db.php");

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$user = $input->user;
$pass = $input->pass;

$db = new DB();
$result = $db->read($user, $pass);

switch($result[0]->mode)
    case "patient":
        header("Location: ../patient.php");
        break;
    case "doc":
        header("Location: ../doc.php");
        break;
    default:
        header("Location: ../index.php?error=" . $result);
        break;
};
```

The console output:

```
GET http://localhost/patient.php                     [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3ms]
```

Since there are no output before invoking header() function, I am not sure what is causing the problem. 
Request for login script is sent by $http.post() angularJS method.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally an angular app would load a new angular route rather than load a whole new page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since HTTP request is sent using some post() method in javascript, it won't redirect your webpage. You'll need to change your PHP login script, to only echo the URL, like:

```
echo "../doc.php";
```

and then redirect the browser using javascript on client side. I'm unfamiliar with $http.post() in angularJS, but you'll need to do this in some success function (which is called once the .post() is successfull) and do the redirection in javascript using

```
location.href=data_received_from_post_request;
```

Comment: Ok, so the problem is that it's wrapped inside angular's ajax method. I see. Thank you!